# Android Issues in playing audio file using media player

Tags: android, audio, media-player

i download audio file from  local server ,and save local path then play that audio file i have issue,i had attached coding and logcat please anyone solve my problem,

### Coding

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
 private static String fileName = "e1.mp3";
 String PATH="/data/data/com.ismail/sounds";
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
       // URL url = new URL("http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp");
         URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.2/supplications/A.1.1.1.mp3");
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

       // String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/download/";
        Log.v("log_tag", "PATH: " + PATH);
        File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("log_tag", "Error: " + e);
    }
    Log.v("log_tag", "Check: ");

    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            try {
                audioPlayer(PATH,fileName);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

 public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        //set up MediaPlayer    
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(PATH);

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
           // mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+filename.mp3);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
    }
 }
```

### LOGCAT ERRORS

```
05-28 20:48:08.604: V/log_tag(6165): PATH: /data/data/com.ismail/sounds
05-28 20:48:18.893: V/log_tag(6165): Check: 
05-28 20:49:06.513: E/MediaPlayer(6165): Unable to to create media player
05-28 20:49:21.778: W/System.err(6165): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
05-28 20:49:21.813: W/System.err(6165):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
05-28 20:49:21.834: W/System.err(6165):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:749)
05-28 20:49:21.853: W/System.err(6165):     at com.ismail.MainActivity.audioPlayer(MainActivity.java:84)
05-28 20:49:21.874: W/System.err(6165):     at com.ismail.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
05-28 20:49:21.903: W/System.err(6165):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-28 20:49:21.936: W/System.err(6165):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-28 20:49:21.964: W/System.err(6165):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-28 20:49:21.983: W/System.err(6165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 20:49:22.004: W/System.err(6165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-28 20:49:22.023: W/System.err(6165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-28 20:49:22.055: W/System.err(6165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 20:49:22.084: W/System.err(6165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-28 20:49:22.103: W/System.err(6165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-28 20:49:22.134: W/System.err(6165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-28 20:49:22.143: W/System.err(6165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 20:49:23.664: E/MediaPlayer(6165): prepareAsync called in state 1
05-28 20:49:55.144: W/System.err(6165): java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-28 20:49:55.164: W/System.err(6165):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
05-28 20:49:55.173: W/System.err(6165):     at com.ismail.MainActivity.audioPlayer(MainActivity.java:97)
05-28 20:49:55.194: W/System.err(6165):     at com.ismail.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
05-28 20:49:55.223: W/System.err(6165):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-28 20:49:55.244: W/System.err(6165):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-28 20:49:55.274: W/System.err(6165):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-28 20:49:55.303: W/System.err(6165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 20:49:55.334: W/System.err(6165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-28 20:49:55.354: W/System.err(6165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-28 20:49:55.374: W/System.err(6165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 20:49:55.394: W/System.err(6165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-28 20:49:55.423: W/System.err(6165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-28 20:49:55.474: W/System.err(6165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-28 20:49:55.495: W/System.err(6165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 20:49:59.664: E/MediaPlayer(6165): start called in state 1
05-28 20:50:09.786: D/dalvikvm(6165): Debugger has detached; object registry had 456 entries
```

Comment: can use  mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); with call back onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/mynpr/source/browse/trunk/mynpr/src/com/webeclubbin/mynpr/StreamingMediaPlayer.java

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below and try:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        try {
             Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
             audioPlayer(PATH,uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


public void audioPlayer(String path, Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException{
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
    mp.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    mp.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the INTERNET permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```